# Sub Component reference giving error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

This is the method which I use to make all fetch calls.

```
static sendJsonRequest(address, action, requestType, jsonData, queryParams, successCallback, errorCallback,showLoader,httpErrorCallback, serverUrl){
    localStorage.setItem("_lastUpdatedTime", Date.now());

    ProjectStore.setLodingCount(ProjectStore.getLodingCount() + 1);
    if(showLoader){
      BusyLoader.showLoader();
    }
    var finalURL = Client.getServiceURL( address, action, queryParams, serverUrl);
    fetch(finalURL, {
      method: requestType,
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
        'pragma': 'no-cache',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache'
      },
      body: String(requestType).toLowerCase() === "get" ? undefined : JSON.stringify(jsonData)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error(response.statusText);
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(jsonObj) {
      if(ProjectStore.getLodingCount() > 0){
        ProjectStore.setLodingCount(ProjectStore.getLodingCount() - 1);
      }
      if(ProjectStore.getLodingCount() === 0){
        BusyLoader.hideLoader();
      }
      successCallback(jsonObj);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      if(ProjectStore.getLodingCount() > 0){
        ProjectStore.setLodingCount(ProjectStore.getLodingCount() - 1);
      }
      if(ProjectStore.getLodingCount() === 0){
        BusyLoader.hideLoader();
      }
        errorCallback(err);
    });
  }
```

I am trying to write the test case for same, everytime I write a test case I am getting error:

```
BusyLoader.objBusyLoader.setState is not a function
```

This is the implementation of `BusyLoader` component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Loading from 'react-loading';
export default class BusyLoader extends Component {
        static objBusyLoader = {};
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            BusyLoader.objBusyLoader = this;
            this.state = {
                    busyIcon:false,
                    color:"#0876b7",
                    width:100,
                    height:100
            };
        }

        static showLoader(){
            BusyLoader.objBusyLoader.setState({
                busyIcon:true
            });
    }

    static hideLoader(){
        BusyLoader.objBusyLoader.setState({
            busyIcon:false
        });
    }

        render(){
        var absStyle = {
            position: "absolute",
            top: "50%",
            left: "50%",
            marginTop: "-50px",
            marginLeft: "-100px",
            zIndex : 2017
        }

        return(<div className="overlay" style={{display : this.state.busyIcon ? "" : "none"}}>
                <div  style={absStyle}>
                    <Loading type='spinningBubbles' color={this.state.color} width={this.state.width}  height={this.state.height}/>
                </div>
            </div>);
    }
}
```

This is the test case I am trying to write

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Client from '../Client.jsx';

describe('<Client />', () => {
  it('should fetch data from service', () => {
    const mockData = {  goodResponse: 'yes' };
    jest.spyOn(window, 'fetch').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(mockData));
    Client.sendJsonRequest();
  });
});
```

Can any one please tell me the issue here and suggest me how to write the case for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a static method (`showLoader`) which tries to call `objBusyLoader.setState`. However `objBusyLoader` is assign in the constructor. This is kind of weired, because having a static method which accesses "instance variables" is a bit "twisted".

At least one instance of `BusyLoader` has to be created to make this work:

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Client from '../Client.jsx';
import BusyLoader from '../BusyLoader.jsx';

describe('<Client />', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    // instantiate the BusyLoader class once, this will assign BusyLoader.objBusyLoader
    shallow(<BusyLoader />);
  })

  it('should fetch data from service', () => {
    const mockData = {  goodResponse: 'yes' };
    jest.spyOn(window, 'fetch').mockImplementation(() => 
      Promise.resolve(mockData));
    Client.sendJsonRequest();
  });
});
```

However, you should definitely review you design as this has "a bad smell".